# Authenticator Not Responding Error BROKER_AUTHENTICATOR_NOT_RESPONDING

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, adal

We are getting the following logs from the ADAL instrumentation on Android and we were just wondering if there is something special we are supposed to be doing to handle this or how we can help our user get past login.

Tue May 22 23:19:13 GMT+02:00 2018:     D/InstrumentationHandler: Event: AuthEvent_LogonAccessError with Properties: {EntityType=Event, ErrorReason=Authenticator is not responding}
Tue May 22 23:19:13 GMT+02:00 2018:     D/InstrumentationHandler: Event: Eng_CustomEvent with Properties: {EventType=AdalAggregatedData, Microsoft.ADAL.correlation_id=7be4c213-0955-4372-91df-099898e72781, Microsoft.ADAL.application_name=<>, Microsoft.ADAL.device_id=<>, Microsoft.ADAL.application_version=1.55.0.2018050703, Microsoft.ADAL.authority_type=aad, Microsoft.ADAL.is_successful=false, EntityType=Event, Microsoft.ADAL.authority_validation_status=yes, Microsoft.ADAL.prompt_behavior=Always, Microsoft.ADAL.api_id=115, Microsoft.ADAL.client_id=<>, Microsoft.ADAL.response_time=33, Microsoft.ADAL.request_id=ea22dac4-e689-4ce5-91f6-0e76aa1567f9, Microsoft.ADAL.api_error_code=BROKER_AUTHENTICATOR_NOT_RESPONDING}

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: It's hard to find an answer just according to your Error massage. Could you post more details about your scneario?

Comment: What more information do you need @WayneYang-MSFT

Comment: Which platform are you using (iOS, Android) and which ADAL library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a previous discussion we had with your team that discusses this.

This could be the result of invalid credentials found in the Intune or Authenticator app. The solution would be to ask the customer to open both of those apps and make sure they are logged in correctly. If that doesn't work, you would need to ask the customer to uninstall/reinstall Intune or Authenticator app (regardless of whether or not they use these apps for your app).

This was originally found on Android, so I am not sure if the same suggestion works for iOS.